# JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean query timeout

Tags: java, web-services, spring, timeout, jax-ws

I'm using a JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean (from Spring framework) to access a web-service. I would like to change the timeout of the http queries I'm sending. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you by advance for any help

Comment: That's going to be configured way below the level of Spring, I'm guessing, and be done in the guts of the JAX-WS implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a way as per the documentation of JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean it has a the following method

```
addCustomProperty(String name, Object value)
```

Use `JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` or `com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout` appropriately.

Check: 
https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/HTTP_Timeouts.html

Comment: I did find this page too, but not the String value of the property. Where did you find it? In which version of which JAXWS library is this property defined? Thanks for your help.